# Add "Part" string to `\part` list in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

Following on my previous question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193802/change-part-counter-to-text-from-i-to-one), I would now like to add the string "Part" to the TOC.

Using a modified thesis style and `\documentclass{report}` which dictates how the TOC appears. I have tried other solutions presented in other questions, but these do not seem to work.

I am currently using:

`\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Numberstring{part}}`

to change the `\part` numbering to a numberstring "One" "Two" etc. I would like the string "Part" to appear in the TOC. Instead of:

One          Some title here

Is there a way to get the TOC listing to be:

Part One     Some title here

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, the "modified thesis style" is the same as in [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193501/) and therefore does not change the definition of "`part`" and that your document uses the original `\@part` definition from `report.sty`:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
        \refstepcounter{part}%

        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart
        \hspace{1em}#1}\else

        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}\fi
   \markboth{}{}%
   {\centering
    \interlinepenalty \@M
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \huge\bf \partname~\thepart
    \par
    \vskip 20\p@\fi
    \Huge \bf
    #2\par}\@endpart}
```

then including

```
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
        \refstepcounter{part}%

        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part \thepart
        \hspace{1em}#1}\else

        \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}\fi
   \markboth{}{}%
   {\centering
    \interlinepenalty \@M
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \huge\bf \partname~\thepart
    \par
    \vskip 20\p@\fi
    \Huge \bf
    #2\par}\@endpart}
\makeatother
```

in your document will work.

I set up an example of how this works at [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/read/rcqpwbdphnvb). *(lines 284-299)*

[image: Output]

Comment: Voila! It does work- it didn't the first time I tried it (after two PDFlatex runs), but after looking at your example code at writeLaTeX, adding the code right before \makeatother (then two more PDFlatex runs), it then seemed to work fine.

Comment: ps. subtle with the Part titles ;)

Comment: Glad it worked. And always remember - including an MWE makes it much easier for the folks at TeX.SX to work on your question. ;)

Comment: Probably why you were the only one to answer having slogged through the MWE in my previous question!

Answer (score 1):

You also can do that with `titlesec/titletoc`.

Specifically, for the case of `\part`, it requires its formatting to be redefined with `\titleformat` and choosing the `newparttoc` option when loading `titlesec`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[newparttoc,explicit, clearempty]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\def\partname{Part}

\renewcommand\thepart{\NUMBERstring{part}}%
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\bfseries\filcenter}{\huge\partname~\thepart}{20pt}{\Huge #1}[\thispagestyle{empty}]%

\titlecontents{part}[0em]{\large\bfseries\protect\addvspace{25pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%
{\contentslabel[\rlap{\partname~\thecontentslabel}]{0em}\hphantom{\partname~\thecontentslabel\quad}}{}%
{,\quad\contentspage}[\addvspace{1ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1ex}]%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{A First Part}
\chapter{Chapter the First}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter the Second}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{Section 2.2}

\part{Another Part} \label{part-2}

\chapter{Chapter the First}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter the Second}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{Section 2.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]